# Well founded recursion in Coq

Tags: math, coq, proof, totality

I am trying to write a function for computing natural division in Coq and I am having some trouble defining it since it is not structural recursion.

My code is:

```
Inductive N : Set :=
  | O : N
  | S : N -> N.

Inductive Bool : Set :=
  | True : Bool
  | False : Bool.

Fixpoint sum (m :N) (n : N) : N :=
match m with
  | O => n
  | S x => S ( sum x n)
end.

Notation "m + n" := (sum m n) (at level 50, left associativity).

Fixpoint mult (m :N) (n : N) : N :=
match m with
  | O => O
  | S x => n + (mult x n)
end.

Notation "m * n" := (mult m n) (at level 40, left associativity).

Fixpoint pred (m : N) : N :=
match m with
  | O => S O
  | S x => x
end.

Fixpoint resta (m:N) (n:N) : N :=
match n with
  | O => m
  | S x => pred (resta m x)
end.
Notation "m - x" := (resta m x) (at level 50, left associativity).

Fixpoint leq_nat (m : N) (n : N) : Bool :=
match m with
  | O => True
  | S x => match n with 
    | O => False
    | S y => leq_nat x y
  end
end.

Notation "m <= n" := (leq_nat m n) (at level 70).

Fixpoint div (m : N) (n : N) : N :=
match n with
  | O => O
  | S x => match m <= n with
    | False => O
    | True => pred (div (m-n) n)
  end
end.
```

As you can see, Coq does not like my function div, it says

> Error: Cannot guess decreasing argument of `fix`.

How can I supply in Coq a termination proof for this function? I can prove that if n>O ^ n<=m -> (m-n) < m.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest strategy in this case is probably to use the `Program` extension together with a `measure`. You will then have to provide a proof that the arguments used in the recursive call are smaller than the top level ones according to the measure.

```
Require Coq.Program.Tactics.
Require Coq.Program.Wf.

Fixpoint toNat (m : N) : nat :=
match m with O => 0 | S n => 1 + (toNat n) end.

Program Fixpoint div (m : N) (n : N) {measure (toNat m)}: N :=
match n with
  | O => O
  | S x => match m <= n with
    | False => O
    | True => pred (div (m-n) n)
  end
end.
Next Obligation.
(* your proof here *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Although gallais's answer is definitely the way to go in general, I should point out that we *can* define division on the natural numbers in Coq as a simple fixpoint. Here, I'm using the definition of `nat` in the standard library for simplicity.

```
Fixpoint minus (n m : nat) {struct n} : nat :=
   match n, m with
   | S n', S m' => minus n' m'
   |    _,    _ => n
   end.

Definition leq (n m : nat) : bool :=
  match minus n m with
  | O => true
  | _ => false
  end.

Fixpoint div (n m : nat) {struct n} : nat :=
  match m with
  | O => O
  | S m' =>
    if leq (S m') n then
      match n with
      | O => O (* Impossible *)
      | S n' => S (div (minus n' m') (S m'))
      end
    else O
  end.

Compute div 6 3.
Compute div 7 3.
Compute div 9 3.
```

The definition of `minus` is essentially the one from the standard library. Notice on the second branch of that definition we return `n`. Thanks to this trick, Coq's termination checker can detect that `minus n' m'` is structurally smaller than `S n'`, which allows us to perform the recursive call to `div`.

There's actually an even simpler way of doing this, although a bit harder to understand: you can check whether the divisor is smaller *and* perform the recursive call in a single step.

```
(* Divide n by m + 1 *)
Fixpoint div'_aux n m {struct n} :=
  match minus n m with
  | O    => O
  | S n' => S (div'_aux n' m)
  end.

Definition div' n m :=
  match m with
  | O    => O (* Arbitrary *)
  | S m' => div'_aux n m'
  end.

Compute div' 6 3.
Compute div' 7 3.
Compute div' 9 3.
```

Once again, because of the form of the `minus` function, Coq's termination checker knows that `n'` in the second branch of `div'_aux` is a valid argument to a recursive call. Notice also that `div'_aux` is dividing by `m + 1`.

Of course, this whole thing relies on a clever trick that requires understanding the termination checker in detail. In general, you have to resort to well-founded recursion, as gallais showed.