# Decreasing argument (and what is a Program Fixpoint)

Tags: coq, termination, totality

Consider the following fixpoint:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive my_type: Type:=
| Left: my_type
| Right: my_type
.

Fixpoint decrease (which: my_type) (left right: list my_type) : list my_type :=
match which with
| Left =>
  match left with
  | [] => []
  | a::tl => decrease a tl right
  end
| Right =>
  match right with
  | [] => []
  | a::tl => decrease a left tl
  end
end.
```

Coq rejects the following fixpoint because it can not guess the decreasing fixpoint (sometimes the `left` list looses its head, sometimes it is the `right` one).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302526/well-founded-recursion-in-coq) shows that one can solve this by using a `Program Fixpoint` and specifying a `{measure ((length left)+(length right))}`.

My questions are:

- What is the difference between a regular `Fixpoint` and a `Program Fixpoint` ?
- Is it possible to explicit the decreasing argument in a regular `Fixpoint` ?
- What is the `Next Obligation` goal ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The `Fixpoint` command in Coq constructs a recursive function using Coq's primitive `fix`, which checks for structural recursion to ensure termination. This is the only recursion in Coq, and all other techniques ultimately desugar to a `fix` of some sort.

  `Program Fixpoint` is a feature of [Program](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/program.html), which allows writing definitions in a slightly extended language that are then compiled into Coq definitions. `Program Fixpoint` accepts any recursive function, generates an appropriate proof obligation that shows the function terminates (by decreasing some measure of its arguments on each recursive subcall), and then packages up the definition and termination proof into a Coq definition that structurally decreases an argument. If that sounds magical it basically is, but [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/GeneralRec.html) gives a good explanation of how to do this kind of encoding.
- Yes, you can add a `{struct arg}` annotation to explicitly specify *which argument is structurally decreasing*: `Fixpoint decrease (which: my_type) (left right: list my_type) {struct right} : list my_type`. This doesn't help for your example, since your function doesn't in general structurally decrease either argument. All primitive `fix` constructs have a `struct` annotation, but Coq can usually infer it automatically when you write a `Fixpoint`. For example, here's `Nat.add`:

  ```
    Nat.add = 
      fix add (n m : nat) {struct n} : nat :=
      match n with
      | 0 => m
      | S p => S (add p m)
      end : nat -> nat -> nat
  ```
- You get two types of goals from `Next Obligation` with `Program Fixpoint`: first that each subcall has a smaller argument (using `measure`, "smaller" is defined using < on nats), and second, that the "smaller" relation is well-founded; this is, it has no infinitely descending sequences of smaller and smaller objects. I'm not sure why `Program Fixpoint` doesn't do this automatically for `Nat.lt`, given that it should know the relevant theorem. Note that `Program` has more features than just more general recursion, so it can generate other goals related to those features as well, depending on the definition you write.