# Defining Addition Over Integers in Coq

Tags: coq

I am following answer from [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40479/standard-constructive-definitions-of-integers-rationals-and-reals) in defining the integers in Coq, but when trying to define addition over it, an error "Cannot guess decreasing argument", always occurs. I have tried multiple different definitions and it always seems to occur. Is there any way to prove for Coq that the argument is decreasing? Or perhaps I am missing some obvious way to define the addition.

```
Inductive nat : Type := (*Natural numbers*)
| O
| S (n : nat).

Fixpoint plus (n:nat) (m:nat) : nat := (*Addition of natural numbers*)
match n with
| O => m
| S(n') => S(plus n' m) 
end.

Notation "x + y" := (plus x y).

Inductive Z := (*Integers*)
  | Positive : nat -> Z   
  | Negative : nat -> Z.  

Fixpoint plus (n:Z) (m:Z) : Z := (*Addition of integers*)
match n, m with
| Positive O , _ => m
| _, Positive O => n
| Negative O , _ => m
| _, Negative O => n
| Positive (S n'), Positive (S m') => Positive (n' + m')
| Positive (S n'), Negative (S m') => plus (Positive n') (Negative m')
| Negative (S n'), Positive (S m') => plus (Positive n') (Negative m') 
| Negative (S n'), Negative (S m') => Negative (n'+ m') 
end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Coq, the only recursive functions you can define are those that perform a recursive call on a *sub-term* of their argument.  Though `Positive n'` is smaller than `Positive (S n')`, which guarantees that your recursive call is safe, it is *not* a sub-term of `Positive (S n')` (one does not literally occur inside the other).  Thus, Coq cannot recognize that your function always terminates, and rejects it.

The solution is to define addition without recursion:

```
Definition plusZ (n1 n2 : Z) : Z :=
  match n1, n2 with
  | Positive n1, Positive n2 => Positive (n1 + n2)
  | Negative n1, Negative n2 => Negative (n1 + n2)
  | Positive n1, Negative n2 =>
    if n2 <=? n1 then Positive (n1 - n2)
    else Negative (n2 - n1)
  | Negative n1, Positive n2 => (* Analogous to the previous case *)
  end.
```

Here, `<=?` refers to the boolean comparison operator on `nat`, and `n1 - n2` refers to truncated subtraction, which yields 0 when `n1 <= n2`. (One thing to watch out about this encoding is that it contains two representations of 0: `Positive 0` and `Negative 0`. You might want to adjust the definition of `plusZ` so that `Negative n` represents `-(n+1)` rather than `-n`, which solves this issue.)

Comment: Azevede De Amorim Thank you for the answer. The addition seems computationally expensive. Is there an alternative in Coq for computing recursive (not primitive recursive) functions? Perhaps that way I could inductively prove that a function always terminates?

Comment: Coq can express general well-founded recursion (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302526/well-founded-recursion-in-coq), though it is somewhat less convenient to use than standard structural recursion. Nevertheless, if you really care about performance, you are probably better off using a binary representation of integers (e.g. the `Z` type in the standard library), or extracting your arithmetic code to a more efficient representation (e.g. https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.extraction.ExtrOcamlBigIntConv.html).